# Set block content from panels / page manager?

Tags: 7, blocks, panels

I am configuring a panels page manager page which also should have a specific sidebar block (search filters related to the page content).

I want to use the regular page.tpl.php where the sidebar is a theme region with blocks. This means the block would NOT be part of the panels layout. I am doing this so that I can get the regular page title and other decorations.

I know that in Display suite it is possible to move some fields into a dedicated region that will be displayed as a sidebar block.

But does something similar exist in panels?

Other options would be to use context module, or to use the regular blocks UI with visibility settings. But in this question I am asking specifically about a solution in panels / page manager.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30731/fill-blocks-from-ctools-page-manager?rq=1 I will check.

Comment: The [linked question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30731/fill-blocks-from-ctools-page-manager) is from 2011, answered in 2012. The given answer does not seem ideal yet. I am going to leave this new question open, in the hope that some new solutions might have popped up since then. Perhaps I will even find a solution by myself.

Comment: One solution could be a "magical layout" where one region goes to a block. I am not aware if this already exists somewhere, but it could be done in custom code.